# DataTables - Select Plugin - multi row select with pagination fails to remember selection

Tags: coffeescript, datatables

I need to make sure that I can use DataTables, 1.10 to use the Select plugin -have pagination set up but the selected items disappear when using server-side processing, I can see dozens of references and hacks, but get the feeling that someone somewhere has solved this issue cleanly

I want to be able to remember the selected rows across pagination.

Coffee script below:

```
    $('#users-table').dataTable
      processing: true
      serverSide: true
      select: true
      rowId: 'row_id'
      deferRender: true
      ajax: $('#users-table').data('source')
      pagingType: 'full_numbers'
      columns: [
        { data: 'name' }
        { data: 'phone' }
        { data: 'address' }
      ]
```

Any obvious solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have defined `rowId` you can store the `id` of selected rows in an array `select`. Upon each draw, cycle through the visible rows for the page and re-select any row that previous has been selected :

```
select = []

# row is selected, add to array
table.on 'select', (e, dt, type, indexes) ->
  rowId = table.row(indexes[0]).id()
  if ! ~select.indexOf(rowId)
    select.push rowId
  return

# row is deselected, remove from array
table.on 'deselect', (e, dt, type, indexes) ->
  rowId = table.row(indexes[0]).id()
  index = select.indexOf(rowId)
  if index > -1
    select.splice index, 1
  return

# on each draw, cycle trough visible rows
# re-select rows if their id appears in the select array 
table.on 'draw', ->
  table.rows().every (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) ->
    if ~select.indexOf(@id())
      @select()
    return
  return
```

Hope it works in coffee script too. Have translated javascript using **http://js2.coffee/**

---

Multi select :

```
table.on 'select', (e, dt, type, indexes) ->
  indexes.forEach (id) ->
    rowId = table.row(id).id()
    if ! ~select.indexOf(rowId)
      select.push rowId
    return
  return

table.on 'deselect', (e, dt, type, indexes) ->
  indexes.forEach (id) ->
    rowId = table.row(id).id()
    index = select.indexOf(rowId)
    if index > -1
      select.splice index, 1
    return
  return
```

Comment: Works but need multi select, should be easy to mod

Comment: @user1320651 OK, It is meant to support multi select (thats how I tested it and why I have used an array)  - but you need to set `select: 'multi'` in the options ...

Comment: Need it to work with select all, also, so its nearly there ;-), its only taking the first select value, but should use rows_selected=table.rows().rows( { selected: true } ) and loop through that to add the values

Comment: could you potentially edit your post to include the select all option?

Comment: @user1320651, you can iterate over `indexes` on `select` / `deselect`? see update. How do you select all?

Comment: Awesome, thats a good solution - sure this will help, using table.rows().select() to select all